# Play!framework 2 - How to configure enough Akka Workers when you keep getting 504

Tags: playframework-2.0, akka

I have a play!framework 2 website with a lot of long-running threads.

We used akka to manage the threads.

Now - we have a lot of 504 responses, and Akka error prints

```
10 Dec 2014 04:10:20.239 [play-akka.actor.promises-dispatcher-406 ] ERROR play                                     - Cannot invoke the action, eventually got an error: Thrown(akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Timed out)
```

We tried configuring it from application.conf many times. But never really resolved the problem. We have a very strong machine. Our current configuration is :

```
play {
  akka {
    event-handlers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jEventHandler"]
    loglevel = WARNING
    actor {
      default-dispatcher = {
        fork-join-executor {
          parallelism-factor = 3.0
          parallelism-max = 128
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What can we do with the configuration to improve the situation?

Comment: Blindly messing with the dispatchers isn't going to help.  You're getting an `AskTimeoutException`, so somewhere you're using `ask`.  Find the one that's timing out and address it (profile, optimize, etc).

Comment: Searched my entire code for `.ask` and did not find results. My target is to allow more operations in parallel.

Comment: Are you using a `?` anywhere?